# traer un elemento diferente en orden a la vez, desde JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

esta vez estoy en esta parte algo atascada, necesito traer los elementos de un JSON, uno a la vez, pero que por cada vez que se ejecute la function me traiga el siguiente en el JSON, en orden, y que al llegar al ultimo elemento vuelva a empezar a mostrarme desde el primer elemento.

```js
function datos(){
  $.get("https://api.myjson.com/bins/ec20e",
  function (data) {
  datone = data[0].uno;
  document.getElementById("traer").innerHTML = datone;
  }, "json");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="datos();">datos</button>
<br>
Elemento de json en orden: <span class="traer" id="traer"></span>
```

sinceramente no tengo la mas mínima idea de hacerlo, sorry. espero puedan entenderme, resumiendo; desde el primer click en el btn, mostrara el uno, luego el dos, tres hasta llegar al diez que es el ultimo del JSON, y cuando así lo haga se reinicie y empieza desde el uno nuevamente.

Comment: Se me ocurre un contador, que lleve la cantidad de clics y asi, sabras que datos mostrar y que si llega a 10 lo reinicies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como ya te dijeron en un comentario, yo lo haria asi:

```js
var data1 = [];
var keys = [];
$.get("https://api.myjson.com/bins/ec20e",
  function (data) {
  data1 = data;
  keys = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(data1[0]);      
}, "json");

var i = 0;
function datos(){
  datone = data1[0][keys[i]];          
  document.getElementById("traer").innerHTML = datone; 
  if (i < keys.length - 1) {
    i++;
  } else {
    i = 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="datos();">datos</button>
<br>
Elemento de json en orden: <span class="traer" id="traer"></span>
```

Comment: Una pregunta. En caso de que sean 50, tendria que hacer 50 case ?

Comment: Si fueran 50, probablemente buscaria una mejor solucion.

Comment: gracias! super, pues @alanfcm la cosa es que realmente son para aproximadamente 150 elementos, 150 cases? Agradecida.

Comment: Ya edite mi respuesta.  150 cases is out of the question.

Comment: @alanfcm bárbaro, DIOS te bendiga. Gracias!